# How to operate on one multidimension numpy array based on values in a different multidimension array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I think what I am trying to do is best illustrated with this example of taking arrays `a` and `b` and producing `expected`:

```
>>> a = np.array([ [ [0,0,0], [0,0,0] ], [ [0,0,0], [0,0,0] ] ])
>>> a
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])

>>> a.shape
(2, 2, 3)

>>> b = np.array([ [3, 7], [9, 8] ])
>>> b
array([[3, 7],
       [9, 8]])
>>> b.shape
(2, 2)

>>> expected = np.array([ [ [3,0,0], [7,0,0] ], [ [9,0,0], [8,0,0] ] ])
>>> expected
array([[[3, 0, 0],
        [7, 0, 0]],

       [[9, 0, 0],
        [8, 0, 0]]])
```

Essentially, for each position in array `a` on axis `1`, I want to visit that position and operate on it based on the corresponding value in array `b` (also axis `1`).

In the example, the function for each position visited might look like this:

```
def _operate(a_val, b_val):
    return a_val + np.array([b_val, 0, 0])
```

(This is just an example and I may want to do other things inside `_operate`, but let's say that at most I'd be adding the value from b to one of the fields in a.)

is there an ideal/correct way to do this in numpy. Thanks!

Comment: `a[...,0] = b`?

Comment: Good call, yes. After I asked this question I realized I could do that, or similarly `a[:, :, 0] = b`.

Thank you

Comment: It's in place, but is actually exactly what I need.